# Refactor formula to avoid exceeding character limit

Tags: formula, governorlimits

I have the following formula field:

```
    IF(AND(TEXT(Method__c)="FedEx Ground", Residential__c = TRUE),"GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY",IF(AND(TEXT(Method__c)="FedEx Ground", Residential__c = FALSE),"FEDEX_GROUND",
    CASE( Method__c, 
    "UPS Ground", "UPS_GROUND", 
    "UPS 3 Day Select", "UPS_THREE_DAY_SELECT", 
    "UPS 2nd Day Air A.M.", "UPS_SECOND_DAY_AIR_AM", 
    "UPS 2nd Day Air", "UPS_SECOND_DAY_AIR", 
    "UPS Next Day Air Early A.M.", "UPS_NEXT_DAY_AIR_EARLY_AM", 
    "UPS Next Day Air", "UPS_NEXT_DAY_AIR", 
    "UPS Next Day Air Saver", "UPS_NEXT_DAY_AIR_SAVER", 
    "UPS Worldwide Express", "UPS_WORLDWIDE_EXPRESS", 
    "UPS Worldwide Expedited", "UPS_WORLDWIDE_EXPEDITED", 
    "UPS Worldwide Saver", "UPS_WORLDWIDE_SAVER", 
    "FedEx 2Day A.M.", "FEDEX_2_DAY_AM", 
    "FedEx 2Day", "FEDEX_2_DAY", 
    "FedEx First Overnight", "FIRST_OVERNIGHT", 
    "FedEx Priority Overnight", "PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT", 
    "FedEx Standard Overnight", "STANDARD_OVERNIGHT", 
    "FedEx Express Saver", "FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER", 
    "FedEx SmartPost", "SMART_POST", 
    "FedEx 3Day Freight", "FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT", 
    "FedEx 2Day Freight", "FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT", 
    "FedEx 1Day Freight", "FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT", 
    "FedEx First Overnight Freight", "FEDEX_FIRST_FREIGHT", 
    "FedEx International Economy", "INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY", 
    "FedEx International Priority", "INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY", 
    "FedEx International First", "INTERNATIONAL_FIRST", 
    null)))
```

I need to modify this formula field to replace the `Method__c` with the field `Method_Override__c` if that field is not blank. I tried to refactor the formula field to the following:

```
    IF
    (
    NOT(ISBLANK(Method__Override__c)), 
    IF(AND(TEXT(Method__Override__c)="FedEx Ground", Residential__c = TRUE),"GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY",IF(AND(TEXT(Method__Override__c)="FedEx Ground", Residential__c = FALSE),"FEDEX_GROUND",
    CASE( Method__Override__c, 
    "UPS Ground", "UPS_GROUND", 
    "UPS 3 Day Select", "UPS_THREE_DAY_SELECT", 
    "UPS 2nd Day Air A.M.", "UPS_SECOND_DAY_AIR_AM", 
    "UPS 2nd Day Air", "UPS_SECOND_DAY_AIR", 
    "UPS Next Day Air Early A.M.", "UPS_NEXT_DAY_AIR_EARLY_AM", 
    "UPS Next Day Air", "UPS_NEXT_DAY_AIR", 
    "UPS Next Day Air Saver", "UPS_NEXT_DAY_AIR_SAVER", 
    "UPS Worldwide Express", "UPS_WORLDWIDE_EXPRESS", 
    "UPS Worldwide Expedited", "UPS_WORLDWIDE_EXPEDITED", 
    "UPS Worldwide Saver", "UPS_WORLDWIDE_SAVER", 
    "FedEx 2Day A.M.", "FEDEX_2_DAY_AM", 
    "FedEx 2Day", "FEDEX_2_DAY", 
    "FedEx First Overnight", "FIRST_OVERNIGHT", 
    "FedEx Priority Overnight", "PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT", 
    "FedEx Standard Overnight", "STANDARD_OVERNIGHT", 
    "FedEx Express Saver", "FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER", 
    "FedEx SmartPost", "SMART_POST", 
    "FedEx 3Day Freight", "FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT", 
    "FedEx 2Day Freight", "FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT", 
    "FedEx 1Day Freight", "FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT", 
    "FedEx First Overnight Freight", "FEDEX_FIRST_FREIGHT", 
    "FedEx International Economy", "INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY", 
    "FedEx International Priority", "INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY", 
    "FedEx International First", "INTERNATIONAL_FIRST", 
    null))), 
    IF(AND(TEXT(Method__c)="FedEx Ground", Residential__c = TRUE),"GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY",IF(AND(TEXT(Method__c)="FedEx Ground", Residential__c = FALSE),"FEDEX_GROUND",
    CASE( Method__c, 
    "UPS Ground", "UPS_GROUND", 
    "UPS 3 Day Select", "UPS_THREE_DAY_SELECT", 
    "UPS 2nd Day Air A.M.", "UPS_SECOND_DAY_AIR_AM", 
    "UPS 2nd Day Air", "UPS_SECOND_DAY_AIR", 
    "UPS Next Day Air Early A.M.", "UPS_NEXT_DAY_AIR_EARLY_AM", 
    "UPS Next Day Air", "UPS_NEXT_DAY_AIR", 
    "UPS Next Day Air Saver", "UPS_NEXT_DAY_AIR_SAVER", 
    "UPS Worldwide Express", "UPS_WORLDWIDE_EXPRESS", 
    "UPS Worldwide Expedited", "UPS_WORLDWIDE_EXPEDITED", 
    "UPS Worldwide Saver", "UPS_WORLDWIDE_SAVER", 
    "FedEx 2Day A.M.", "FEDEX_2_DAY_AM", 
    "FedEx 2Day", "FEDEX_2_DAY", 
    "FedEx First Overnight", "FIRST_OVERNIGHT", 
    "FedEx Priority Overnight", "PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT", 
    "FedEx Standard Overnight", "STANDARD_OVERNIGHT", 
    "FedEx Express Saver", "FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER", 
    "FedEx SmartPost", "SMART_POST", 
    "FedEx 3Day Freight", "FEDEX_3_DAY_FREIGHT", 
    "FedEx 2Day Freight", "FEDEX_2_DAY_FREIGHT", 
    "FedEx 1Day Freight", "FEDEX_1_DAY_FREIGHT", 
    "FedEx First Overnight Freight", "FEDEX_FIRST_FREIGHT", 
    "FedEx International Economy", "INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY", 
    "FedEx International Priority", "INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY", 
    "FedEx International First", "INTERNATIONAL_FIRST", 
    null)))
    )
```

This exceeds the 5,000 character limit for formula fields. I could use a combination of new fields and workflows to set values and use those fields within this formula to reduce the character limit. However, I was trying to avoid creating new fields and workflows. Is there a better approach to refactoring the formula field to get the desired result?

Comment: Are these both picklist fields?  Have you considered using the [API value functionality](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_picklist_protect.htm&type=5) to do this?

If you can't use the API value, look at using `UPPER()` and `SUBSTITUTE()` functions in the formula to consolidate the easy transformations, e.g. UPPER(SUBSTITUTE("Fedex Express Saver", " ", "_")) will give you FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER.  You won't save much due to the inconsistencies in your transformed values though.

Comment: I think I can make it work with the API value functionality. Thanks for the suggestion!!